# Spark batches does not complete when running on Yarn cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, couchbase, hadoop-yarn

**Setting the scene**
I am working to make a Spark streaming application (Spark 2.2.1 with Scala) run on a Yarn cluster (Hadoop 2.7.4).

So far I managed to submit the application to the Yarn cluster with spark-submit. I can see that the receiver task starts up correctly and fetches a lot of records from the database (Couchbase Server 5.0) and I can also see that the records are divided into batches.

**The question**
When I look at the Streaming Statistics on the Spark Web UI, I can however see that my batches are never processed. I have seen batches with 0 records process and complete but when a batch with records start processing it never completes. One time it even got stuck on a batch with 0 records.

I even tried simplifying the output operations on the SteamingContext as much as possible. But still with the very simple output operation print() my batches are never processed. The logs does not show any warnings or errors.

Does anyone know what might be wrong? Any suggestions on how to solve this will be much appreciated.

**More Info**
The main class of the Spark application is built from [this example](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/connectors/spark-2.2/spark-streaming.html) (first one) from the Couchbase Spark Connector documentation combined with [this example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing) with checkpoint from the Spark Documentation.

Right now I have 3230 Active Batches (3229 queued and 1 processing) and 1 Completed Batch (that had 0 records) and the application has been running for 4 hours and 30 minutes... and another batch is added every 5 seconds.

If I look at the "thread dump" for the executors I see a lot of WAITING, TIMED WAITING and a few RUNNABLE threads. The list will fill up 3 screenshots, so i will only post it if needed.

Below you will find some screenshots from the Web UI

**Executor Overview**
[image]

**Spark Jobs Overview**
[image]

**Node Overview with resources**
[image]

**Capacity Scheduler Overview**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per screenshot, you have 2 cores and 1 is being used for driver and another is being used for receiver. You don't have a core for the actual processing to happen. Please increase the number of cores and try again.

Refer: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#input-dstreams-and-receivers

If you are using an input DStream based on a receiver (e.g. sockets, Kafka, Flume, etc.), then the single thread will be used to run the receiver, leaving no thread for processing the received data. Hence, when running locally, always use “local[n]” as the master URL, where n > number of receivers to run (see Spark Properties for information on how to set the master).

Comment: Thank you. I will try that today and let you know if it solved my problem.

Comment: Actually the nodemanager has 3 cores available. Apparently 1 is reserved for operating system/scheduler. That leaves 2 vCores but they are both used for the 2 containers.

Comment: I run spark-submit with these parameters. 
 --master yarn 
 --deploy-mode cluster 
 --driver-cores 1 
 --driver-memory 2G 
 --num-executors 2 
 --executor-cores 1 
 --executor-memory 1G 

So the core I am missing is the one for the driver?

Comment: If you look at the executor UI, you can see two executors are there and out of that one is the driver process. Even though you have requested for 2 executors, YARN allocated only one. How many nodes are there in your YARN cluster? if your Yarn cluster has only one node, then you will require 4 cores for 2 executor / 1 for driver and 1 for OS/Scheduler. Currently you are getting only one executor with 1 core + 1 driver.

Comment: Additionally, spark will submit tasks only when the (registered resources / total expected resources) >=  "spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio". The ""spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio" for spark in YARN is 0.8, which means spark will submit tasks only when atleast 80% of requested resources is provided by YARN. So please ensure that the requested resources are atleast 80% of what YARN can provide.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Batches started processing after I added an extra core. Now the node has 8GB RAM and 4 cores.